Is there a way to get the underlying client from a resource in AWS?
I am trying to use the boto3 extensibility guide and I am unable to register an event system for an sqs resource. I think I may be able to fix it by using the underlying client for the resource.
Is there a way to access the client for AWS_SESSION.resource('sqs')? Thank you!

Glad you figured it out! Rather than putting the Answer inside your Question, please add your own Answer so that future readers will discover it.

It can be done by doing resource.meta.client!
